# Powershell - Uninstalling a List of Programs Taking Too Long

Tags: powershell

I am looking for assistance on making a bit of code more efficient. I currently have a simple Powershell script (part of a larger script) that enumerates items from a text file (namely the string used to identify an installed program) and then tries uninstalling each of those strings using msiexec:

```
$javaUninstall = Get-Content .\jre-uninstall-list.txt
    foreach ($java in $javaUninstall) {
    write-host "Trying", "$java"
    $app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
        $_.IdentifyingNumber -match "$java"
    }
    &cmd /c "msiexec /uninstall $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /passive /quiet"
}
```

This code correctly uninstalls any version of 32-bit Java from Java 5 and on that is present on the system. However, it takes **forever**. Each item runs for 5-10 seconds - and then it moves on to the next. Is there any way to have it quickly skip over versions that are not found? Using a batch file this runs in under 15 seconds flat.

Comment: I think part of your issue is you are invoking the command shell for each uninstall.  Try executing msiexec directly.

Comment: So take the last line and change it to: msiexec /uninstall $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /passive /quiet ?

Comment: Gave that a whirl. It still worked correctly, but there wasn't a great improvement in the execution time compared to the standard batch file.

Comment: Should `$_.IdentifyingNumber -match "$java"` be `$_.Name -match "$java"`? Otherwise, if `$java` already contains the IdentifyingNumber, why would you query for it?

Comment: The $_.IdentifyingNumber piece actually represents something like this: {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83217055FF} - Name would be something like "Java 7 Update 55" - what this does is looks at the Win32_Product list and finds programs that match the IdentifyingNumbers listed in the text file instead of Name, as Name might end up with false positives.

Comment: I'd suspect the slow down is in the repeated WMI calls.  Can you post the batch file you are comparing too?  Does it do similar WMI calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `$java` variable already contains the IdentifyingNumber, just use it directly with `msiexec`.

```
$javaUninstall = Get-Content .\jre-uninstall-list.txt
foreach ($java in $javaUninstall) {
    write-host "Trying", "$java"
    msiexec /uninstall $java /passive /quiet
}
```

Comment: This is a great find. I need to call cmd /c anyway though, as the process fails if more than one Java installation exists due to the fact that it doesn't wait. So I do a cmd /c START /WAIT... and so forth. I appreciate the help, this made it much faster.

Comment: @Tim, can't you do `Start-Process -Wait` instead of calling cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

As @dangph said, here is the PowerShell code below so you don't have to call `CMD /C` commands, and the user now only has to fill out the variables instead of playing with the syntax as well.

It's not much of a change I know, but the user doesn't have to worry about messing up a script that may otherwise be ok, if they need to change the script often, as I do with my scripts.

```
$javaUninstall = Get-Content -Path .\jre-uninstall-list.txt
$args = "/x $java /passive /quiet"
$msi = "msiexec"
foreach ($java in $javaUninstall) {
    write-host "Trying", "$java"
    Start-Process -FilePath $msi -ArgumentList $args -Wait -PassThru
}
```

Comment: Sure @DavidPostill, the user now only has to fill out the variables instead of playing with the syntax as well. It's not much of a change I know, but the user (if new to powershell, and remember that this answers not just for the person asking but anyone who also comes across this question) doesn't have to worry about messing up a script that may otherwise be ok, if they need to change the script often, as I do with my scripts.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sure, no problems :)

Comment: I did the edit on my iPhone via the app so not sure if it has messed up the layout and the code block sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You could spin off each item in its own powershell instance.  The solution I'm providing will likely be the most resource intensive (FYI).  I don't want to take credit for another's work, so I'll link the script example provided [HERE.](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/14004-how-start-cmdlet-without-waiting-finish.html)

You'll could build the example into a function, and then iterate the function inside your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Only one MSI install/uninstall can be running at once. Spinning off separate instances would lead to collisions.

Comment: @ebgreen not in windows 7