# Uninstall set of programs using Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have a set of programs I would like to uninstall with Powershell.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | where-Object {$_.name -Like "MySQL*"}
```

How do I pipe this to an uninstall function?

Some [questions](https://superuser.com/q/747106/141215) seems to use `msiexec`, but [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48224594/1079075) recommend `.uninstall()`?

Comment: Find some useful tips here https://superuser.com/q/1483618/471143.

Comment: you will likely have to loop through the results and run each uninstall, waiting for them to complete.

Comment: Avoid Win32_Product when ever possible - "This process also initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install."  See the Warning on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394378(v=vs.85)

Comment: Also note that if the packages have dependencies on each other, you may not be able to uninstall them in the order returned. hopefully that is not the case.

Comment: Do you know all the applications to remove are MSI based?

Comment: @HelpingHand I don't think they are msi-based, given they were installed as a bundle from another installer.

Comment: There are quite a lot of cases to consider to create a generic uninstaller, especially if you want it silent and how to reference the components you want to remove, e.g. "DisplayName"? I just put this together, I haven't really tested it much - https://pastebin.com/PK0fEUMC The idea being you can define the applications to remove by DisplayName and optionally set an additional argument if needed, i.e. to make it silent.  It will use the QuietUninstallString value if it exists.  Maybe something to start from?

Comment: Try something like `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product -Filter "name like 'MySQL%'"|Foreach-Object {$_|Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Uninstall}`

Comment: Win32_Product is not a good option and it only covers packages installed by Windows Installer. Software that doesn't use Windows Installer will not be listed.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the existing output and call `Uninstall()` for each product:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | where-Object {$_.name -Like "MySQL*"} | ForEach-Object { $_.Uninstall() }
```

Just be very sure you want to uninstall every product starting with "MySQL".

It should also be quicker if you do your filtering from the WMI query:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "name LIKE 'MySQL%'" | ForEach-Object { $_.Uninstall() }
```